# If $\lambda(A_n \cap A_k) = 0$ then $\lambda \left( \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda(A_n)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A_n$ be borel set such that $\lambda(A_n \cap A_k) = 0 \quad \mbox{for} \quad n\neq k$. $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Show that $$\lambda \left( \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda(A_n)$$

I would like show that $\lambda(A_n \cap A_k) = 0$ implies that $A_n \cap A_k = \emptyset$ but I think it may be not true, for example if I get $A_n = \mathbb{Q}$ and $A_k = \mathbb{R}$

Anyone can help?

Comment: Sets can have (Lebesgue-)measure zero without being the empty set, you're correct there (singleton points have this property).  However, you might be able to start by observing that $\lambda (A\cup B) = \lambda(A) + \lambda(B) - \lambda(A \cap B)$ if $\lambda (A \cap B) < \infty$ and go from there.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607010/prove-that-mu-left-cup-k-1-infty-a-k-right-sum-k-ge1-mua-k?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

HINT: show by induction on $N\ge 0$ that
$$\lambda \left(\bigcup_{k=0}^N A_k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^N \lambda(A_k)$$
Then send $N \to + \infty$, recalling that $\left\{ \bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k\right\}_{N\ge0}$ is an increasing chain of Borel sets.